# API Gateway Custom headers won't persist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to add a [custom header to an API Gateway resource](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/). I select the resource on API Gateway and select `Enable CORS`. Then add `custom-header` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` comma separated list. No matter what I do I can't save the new custom header to Api gateway.  I'm following the [Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/authz/q/platform/js).

`'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,my-custom-header'`. Api gateway shows successfully added. But when I go back to enable CORS I don't see the update. I have also redeployed the api, but it still does not reflect the new change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be thrown when the API call is not authorized properly. The CORS errors can be shown even if it is not a CORS error.

I had the same issue in trying to use amplify with an existing API gateway. I used the following article to help fix this issue. https://www.qloudx.com/using-angular-to-invoke-apis-hosted-on-amazon-api-gateway-secured-using-cognito-user-pools/?unapproved=53&moderation-hash=3e2d91efec236374c2e551b5810590f8#comment-53

If might not be the solution you are looking for but does help you get moving in the right direction.